# Regex: Decimal with constraints and certain alpha characters allowed at the end

Tags: regex

Figure I'll put this here for posterity.

**What is the regex for `####.@@@@X`?**

- Where "#" is any number up to 4 digits before the decimal point but **only one leading 0 allowed**
- Where "@" is any number up to 4 digits after the decimal point
- Where "X" is a single alpha character in a given list (`A or a`, `X or x`) that must come last

**Examples to pass:**

- .309x
- 0.309
- 1
- 0.0
- 1.0234
- 0.2345X (IMPORTANT, should only allow one leading 0)
- 1.23A
- 7300.3211x
- 0.1a

**Examples to fail:**

- 01.123
- 00.234
- a.123
- 1.23p
- 00.43x

**What I have now:**

- `^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,4})?$`
- This works for 4 numbers before and after decimal
- But doesn't account for the the single leading 0 NOR the alpha at the end.

**EDIT 1:**

- Testing your solutions made me realize some other cases.
- I updated the pass/fail scenarios
- The biggest revelations are:

  - The leading number is optional
  - The decimal point is optional
  - The alpha character at the end is optional
  - A leading 0 should only be followed the decimal point.

    - e.g: 0.123 yes; 01.234 no

**Answers:**

- @TheFourthBird and @AaronMorefield got it with these:

```
^(?!00|0[1-9]\.)(?:\d{0,4}\.\d{1,4}[aAxX]?|\d{1,4})$

((^[1-9])(\d{0,3})|^0|^)((\.?)\d{0,4})(|[A-Za-z])$
```

I'll be studying these!

Comment: Like `^(?!00)\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}[aAxX]$` https://regex101.com/r/7uYMaz/1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?!00|0[1-9]\.)(?:\d{0,4}\.\d{1,4}[aAxX]?|\d{1,4})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!00|0[1-9]\.)` Negative lookahead to exclude matching 00 or 01-9. at the start
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{0,4}\.\d{1,4}` Match 0-4 digits, a `.` and 1-4 digits
  - `[aAxX]?` Optionally match a or x lower and uppercase variants
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,4}` Match 1-4 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4aTmx/1/)

Comment: Similarly, does not allow 1 nor 0.1. Your answer made me rethink (thank you). Updated pass/fail cases in OP.

Comment: @ericOnline Why should `01.123` fail?

Comment: Believe it or not, I'm trying to find a regex for "mileposts" (roadside markers). These have a very specific system of numbering that must be verbally repeated(!). There actually is no "zero one point one two three" allowed. Only "one point one two three".

Comment: @ericOnline So like `^(?!00|0[1-9]\.)(?:\d{0,4}\.\d{1,4}[aAxX]?|\d{1,4})$` https://regex101.com/r/S4aTmx/1

Comment: You got iT! This seems to tick all the boxes!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```java
^(?!00)\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}[aAxX]?)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DlWLcb/3). It also allows numbers without period.

**Explanation**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    00                       '00'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 4 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 4 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [aAxX]?                  any optional character of: 'a', 'A', 'x', 'X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Almost. This one does not allow 0.01.

Comment: @ericOnline The letter at the end must be turned optional, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ericOnline It is compliant with your updated requirements.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt =)

```
^(?!.*\d{5}|0\d)\d{0,4}\.?\d{1,4}[aAxX]?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4zS8T/5)

I took your "single leading 0" as though you just wanted to allow for "0.1" but disallow "01.1". Therefor I added an alternation within a non-capturing group. I guess I might be wrong looking at the other answers.

Comment: Does not allow 0.1 nor 1. Your answer forced me to rethink. I edited pass/fail cases above.

Comment: @ericonline. Can you check the edit. I disallowed a single zero as the whole input. Let me know if that's correct.

Comment: Darn near! Just misses `.345` (optional leading number).

Comment: @Ericonline. I edited the answer to your requirements I think. Can you check? Mind you, you didn't mention anything about 0, or 0a etc, so the expression does allow for that currently.

Comment: Also the other answers allow for things like 012. Can you elaborate on if that's allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This matches your set without using any calculated look-arounds:

```regex
((^[1-9])(\d{0,3})|^0|^)((\.?)\d{0,4})(|[A-Za-z])$
```

This checks that the beginning of the string is any number 1 through 9 with three optional numbers afterwards, or exactly one leading zero. Then the explicit full-stop with up to 4 digits after, then optionally any Alpha numeric character and the end-string anchor.

Check the link to this Regex here: https://regex101.com/r/mBzNuN/2

Comment: This one seems to be the closest. Just needs to accept a single whole number without the decimal too. eg: 1. Your answer made me rethink my OP. Made an edit for pass/fail cases.

Comment: Thanks, @ericOnline: I believe adding a plus after the `\.` should get me there with this case added. Just out of curiousity: can you explain to me why "1.23p" should fail and "1.23A" Should pass? Is it the capitalization, the letter, or a typo?

Comment: @ericOnline I have updated my answer to match your new test cases. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Misses `1` and `.345` (whole number and optional leading number)

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to give the new URL, one second

Comment: @ericOnline The URL Should be up to date!

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:|0|[1-9]\d{0,3})(?:\.\d{1,4})?(?<!^)[AaXx]?$`

- `(?:|0|[1-9]\d{0,3})` : Before decimal point: Nothing or 0 or any number up to 4 digits ...
- `(?:\.\d{1,4})?` : Decimal part (Optional)
- `(?<!^)` : (lookbehind) verifies that there is an integer and/or decimal part
- `[AaXx]?` : The alpha character at the end is optional